# Regex to find certain characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing this in Javascript, so there might be an easier way?  However I have a string that looks like this:

`designs/<random_id>/<random_id>/icon_<random_id>.png`

An example of this would be:

`designs/DMFSx881yveor8qolW7DUuPxWDQ2/e53BqQG2Y3wnn8uVRw8m/icon_a5898064.png`

What I want to do is to check to see if this string ends with `icon_<random_id>.png`  If it does, do X, otherwise do nothing

I'm not very good at Regex.  I've tried `^icon\_{*}\.png$` but I'm not having a lot of joy

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @UllasHunka indexOf won't work with a random_id

Comment: Added in what I have tried, and continuing to try

Comment: what can the randomId consists of? your regex accepts only numbers but the example also has the letter "a" in there

Comment: I've just edited it to `^icon\_{*}\.png$`  The random string is made up of alphanumeric character including lower and upper case

Comment: `^icon\_[A-Za-z0-9]{*}\.png$` this should do the trick if the randomId consists of numbers and lower+upper case letters

Comment: Sorry Philipp, i've just realised what you meant.  The random id after the icon_ can be anything acceptable for filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to simple check is the partial exist or not :

```
let reg = /(icon_[\S]+\.png)$/iu; 


let str = 'designs/DMFSx881yveor8qolW7DUuPxWDQ2/e53BqQG2Y3wnn8uVRw8m/icon_a5898064.png';

let check = str.match(reg);

if(Array.isArray(check) && check[0]) {
console.log('exists');
}else{
console.log('not exists');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That one matches your use case :

```
\/icon_(\w+)\.png$
```

Then you can do something like :

```
var matches = str.match(/\/icon_(\w+)\.png$/g);
```

Comment: This one almost works for my use case.  The random string after icon_ can be anything acceptable and it doesn't appear to work for all characters

Answer (score 0):

I would think something like `/(icon_[A-z0-9]+.png)$/`might be what you're looking for.

```
var img-reg = /(icon_[A-z0-9]+.png)$/;
var url = 'designs/DMFSx8uPxWDQ2/e53BqQG2Y3wnn8uVRw8m/icon_a58598064.png'; 
if (img-reg.test(url)) {
    //do something because it matched.
}
```

icon_ + any amount of numbers or letters followed by .png and the $ represents that it has to be at the end of the string. when you use a ^ at the beginning you state that the start has to match too.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for your purpose:

```
^.*icon\_[a-z,0-9]*\.png$
```

Comment: you need to escape _ and .

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I'll edit the answer. This regex worked without the escaped characters on regexr.com for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`/icon\_[A-z0-9]{8}\.png/`

tested with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jYMUGm/1/). It also provides a good explanation of how the regex works.

- icon matches the characters icon literally (case sensitive)
- _ matches the character _ literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [A-z0-9]{8}
- {8} Quantifier — Matches exactly 8 times
- A-z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
- 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- png matches the characters png literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

```
if x = 'your string'
y = x.match(/\/icon_[^/]+.png/);
```

if this return value to y then x string you needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`designs\/[A-Za-z0-9]*\/[A-Za-z0-9]*\/icon_[A-Za-z0-9]*.png`